# Recovering data from hard disk after an accidental Ubuntu reinstallation

Tags: data-recovery

My computer got wiped accidentally due to a fresh Ubuntu installation. 
Since the drive contains very important data and codes, it would be really great if the same could be recovered.

It is a 2TB hard drive which had Ubuntu 10.10 earlier. It now has a Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it (which I understand occupies ~4GB). The machine has been powered off since.

The installation was done using a usb with the option where the previous ubuntu installation is removed. 
Since installation doesn't take a lot of time, I'm inclined to think that the disk wasn't completely formatted and that most of the data is still there.

I have no experience with recovery and hence a detailed explanation is very helpful.

NOTE: I can arrange an additional 2TB hard disk for copying data. My computer has a fast internet connection and I have other computers connected to the network which I may use to access the previous one as well.

Comment: Take a look at [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same thing happened to me. I managed to recover all my data with testdisk.

In my case I had 2 partitions - the Ubuntu install formatted my drive and deleted my second partition with all my data.
I simply re-enabled the partition (I think I set it from deleted to logical..) and I could access everything from Ubuntu again.
It was also possible to copy the files from within testdisk to another drive/partition.

Good luck!

Comment: Was the folder structure intact as well?